# Eclipse Papyrus DataSet for Class and Sequence Diagram

Tags: eclipse, class-diagram, sequence-diagram, papyrus

I am currently doing my research which involves source code generation based on class and sequence diagram. My problem is that I want a dataset on which I can test my tool. I am not able to find example projects of class and sequence Diagrams.
Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.
Multitude of Thanks.